# Match all text between two tags? With beautifulsoup4, or is there a better answer?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

The html I'm trying to match is something like this...

```
...
<!-- Start Body -->
Paragraph 1<br><br>
Paragraph 2<br><br>
<!-- End Body -->
...
```

The site I'm scraping is old, so from page to page it can change from br's to paragraph tags, etc. It's a mess, the only sure thing is that all the content I need is between the start body and end body comment tags.

What's the best way to do this? Should I even be using beautifulsoup or is that overkill?

Comment: This is one of those times where it's ok to use regex

Answer (score 1):

I'd just grab the text directly, without BeautifulSoup:

```
start = "<!-- Start Body -->"
end = "<!-- End Body -->"
html = "..." # Page HTML

_s = html.find(start)
_e = html.find(end)
if _s != -1 and _e != -1:
  found = html[_s + len(start):_e]
```

There might be an off-by one in the last line, but that should get you started. You'll also need to decide what to do if the tags appear multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> html = '''
... ...
... <!-- Start Body -->
... Paragraph 1<br><br>
... Paragraph 2<br><br>
... <!-- End Body -->
... ...
... '''
>>> chunk = html.split('<!-- Start Body -->')[1].split('<!-- End Body -->')[0]
>>> print(chunk)

Paragraph 1<br><br>
Paragraph 2<br><br>
```

- `html.split('<!-- Start Body -->')[1]` - get part after the `Start Body` comment
- `.split('<!-- End Body -->')[0]` - get part before the `End Body` comment

---

Alternative using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('<!-- Start Body -->(.+?)<!-- End Body -->', html, flags=re.S)
['\nParagraph 1<br><br>\nParagraph 2<br><br>\n']
```